# C# solution to always check for a specific condition in system

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my system, I have to send sms to users whose accounts are expired on the day of expiration.  So I'm thinking of a solution to check all accounts everyday regardless of other functionality of the server so I was guessing a service should do the job? I'm looking for the best practice.

Comment: well nothing yet, I'm just trying to understand what is the best solution, I'm not looking for any code , just a best practice, the rest I'll figure it out myself. I'm thinking of a c# service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a task that you want to run once a day, a service is not necessary. You can simply use the Task Scheduler to schedule a task thats run your C# program at the same time each day.

That way you don't have to do the extra work of writing a service, and you don't have a process running all the time that just sits there waiting all day.

Comment: What you mentioned makes more sense for my case. thanks I'm accepting yours as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a service that send sms and call that when accounts is expired on the day of expiration

Comment: Yea a service with a timer should do the job in my case, but is it the best practice for my case ?